# Symfony Doctrine SortBy ToMany relation objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have entity post and points, the are connected by oneToMany relation. I want make method that will return objects with most count of related comments. 
Is it possible?
Please help, i don't have any idea.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/ordered-associations.html - should i use this?

entities:
post:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Points
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Points", mappedBy="post", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $points;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Points[]
     */
    public function getPoints(): Collection {
        return $this->points;
    }

...
```

points

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PointsRepository")
 */
class Points
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Post
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="points",  fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $post;

    public function getPost(): Post {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function setPost(Post $post ){
        $this->post = $post;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you are already able to return a post with its points you might try something like this:

in App\Repository\PostRepository:

```
public function postsByPoints() {
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p.post, count(pt.points) N)
        ->from('App:Points', 'pt')
        ->join('pt.post', 'p')
        ->where('some where clause') <- delete this if you're not selecting a subset
        ->groupBy('p.post')
        ->orderBy('N')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

In some controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$postsByPoints = $em->getRepository('App:Post')->postsByPoints();
```

NB: not tested

Comment: nearly ok, `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'post, count(pt.points)': Error: Class App\Entity\Post has no field or association named post`

Answer (score 0):

This is an working (for me) code

```sql
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.user', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('p.points', 'pp')
            ->andWhere("p.date > '".$now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'")
            ->setMaxResults($max)
            ->groupBy('pp.post')
            ->orderBy('pp.post','DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```